# MSSQL Edit date (YEAR, MONTH) in one command

Tags: sql, function, date, datetime, getdate

I need manipulate with time in one command. I have this date "15.02.2013" and now i need this time change on this "15.01.2012". Date is dynamic stats for me. i need change time with this functions (GATEDATE, YEAR, MONTH) or others.

INPUT:

```
"15.02.2013"
```

I need this output:

```
"15.01.2012"
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: So, what do you need exactly? Do you need to set date back of 1 year and 1 month? Or what?

Comment: For date i using declaration. Now i selecting data from SQL by date. But now i know how can i change year, month or day). But if i want select data from SQL where i need change date while by year and month

Comment: Still I don't understand your needs...

Comment: My input time is example: 15.02.2013 - > @date_from
ok if i want change date i using this dateadd(month, -1, @date_from)
Output is this: 15.01.2013

But i need earn this in one command
15.01.2012

Comment: So use `DATEADD(year, -1, dateadd(month, -1, @date_from))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a double `DATEADD` on the same value.

I.e.

```
SELECT DATEADD(year, -1, DATEADD(month, -1, @date_from)) FROM Table1
```

The inner `DATEADD` is your original, which subtracts the month. This is then wrapped in a second `DATEADD` which subtracts the year. Alternatively, if it's always 1 year and one month, you could easily subtract 13 months:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, -13, @date_from))
```

You could even choose to have a [computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in your table using the function to calculate the date.